# Google Chrome on iOS does not shift viewport on input field focus unlike Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, google-chrome

I noticed some odd behavior with Google Chrome for iOS in contrast to how Safari behaves. For some reason, Google Chrome does not shift the viewport when clicking on an input field, which can often result in input fields being hidden on Chrome. Funnily, this behavior also occurs on Google's own homepage, where the input field is partially hidden and Google's search suggestions are completely hidden in Chrome:

[image: Google Homepage in Chrome for iOS]

On Safari, however, the viewport is moved up so that the input fields and all suggestions are visible:

[image: Google Homepage in Safari for iOS]

This makes developing for iOS devices a bit of a pain since some users will not have the same experience when filling out forms or search fields which are not aligned to the top. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? Is there maybe some non-standard CSS which forces Chrome to shift the keyboard? Or is this maybe something that could be considered a bug in Chrome for iOS?